# Merge 200 + Excel Files into 1

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a folder with 200+ excel files. I have the respective path and sheet names for each file in the folder. Is it possible to merge all of these files into one or a couple large excel file via python? If so, what libraries would be good for me to start reading up on for this type of script?

I am trying to condense the files into 1-8 excel files in total not 200+ excel files.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For example, suppose there are a.xlsx, b.xlsx, c.xlsx.

With using `os`(by `import os`) and `endswith` method, you can take all xlsx files.(You would easily find how to do it)

Then, read xlsx files in the loop(`for` or `while` statement) and with pandas and add it into a new excelwriter like below

e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter('goal.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

while True:
   df = pd.read_excel('excel_file_path')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(sheet_number))

writer.save()
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
import os

excelfolder = 'path to the folder'

path_names = []

for root, folder, files in os.walk(excelfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            path_names.append(filename)

So, I got all of the path names, but I am passing in a list into: 
for x in path_names: 
      df = pd.read_excel('excel_file_path')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(sheet_number))

writer.save()

Comment: @Jessica, it's so complicated... Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did not figure it out yet, I wrote a script and it is going loop for over an hour. I assume there is some error with the for loop.

Comment: @Jessica Can you attach the code in the question so that I can see what's the problem with the code? It is hard to see if the code is expressed like here in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to directory where all csv are located (eg cd C:\Temp)
2. Click on the file directory and type "cmd"; this will open a command prompt at the file location.
3. Type "copy *.csv combine.csv"

(Replace "csv" with the type of excel file you have, however this will probably work best with csv files)